# Which of (unsigned char)str vs str + 0xff or (unsigned int)value vs value + 0xffff Is Faster and Preferred Method?

Tags: c++, c

I want to know which of the following constructs is preferred and faster.

`unsigned char str1 = (unsigned char)str2` vs `unsigned char str1 = str2 & 0xff`
or
`unsigned value1 = (unsigned)value2` vs `unsigned value1 = value2 & 0xffffffff`

*Questions:*
 - by converting from to:
 - Is 1st faster than 2nd (`0xff` or `0xffffffff`)?
 - Which do you prefer to use? and which is better to use?
 - Can `(unsigned char)str` can be changed as `str & 0xff`?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: What?  These aren't doing the same thing...

Comment: Do you mean `str & 0xff` ? I'm not sure why you're asking this but your answer depends very much on what you're trying to acheive. Could you clarify the context?

Comment: I edited question should be clear now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No two of those four code snippets do the same thing. Any speed difference between them is both irrelevant (since code that runs faster but does the wrong thing is worthless) and negligible (they're all pretty fast).

Edit for updated question:

Assuming that `CHAR_BIT == 8`, and that `str` is one of: an unsigned integer; a signed integer with positive value; a signed integer with 2's complement representation; then `(unsigned char) str` gives the same numeric result as `str & 0xff`, but with a different type. Whichever one you write, the compiler will pick a fast way to compute that result, quite possibly the same way in both cases. So you may as well just write `unsigned char str1 = str2;`, and add the cast to `(unsigned char)` if needed to suppress any compiler warning you get for an implicit conversion that loses information.

On most implementations, `unsigned` is a 32 bit type, in which case `(unsigned)value2` produces different values from `value2 & 0xffff` for `value2` greater than 65535. Leaving that aside (so assuming you're on a 16 bit implementation), it's the same deal as with `unsigned char` except that provided `value2` also has type `unsigned` then the results have the same type as well as the same value.

Comment: yes you are absolutely right, but it should be **`0xffffffff`** not **`0xffff`** my mistake, sorry about that. so by converting value from to I'll get same value and does not matter if I use `(unsigned)value` or `value & 0xffffffff`.`If 0xff is equal 255 what value of haxdecimal will be for (-128-127)?`

Comment: @Make: I'm not sure I understand the question. -128-127 is -255. Obviously this cannot be represented in any unsigned type, since it is negative. It cannot be represented in a signed type in any less than 9 bits. Its 16-bit 2's complement representation is `0xFF01`, but be careful there, because in C the literal `0xFF01` doesn't represent -255, it represents 65281. Rule of thumb, don't try to use hex literals for negative values.

Comment: Thanks Steve. (-128,+127) signed byte

Answer (score 0):

The effect of the casts highly depends on the type of `str` and `value`.
E.g. if `str` is `unsigned char`, casting it to `unsigned char` does nothing, for good or bad. If it's `int` it changes things, and if a pointer - it's another matter completely.

Regarding performance - it's the last thing you should worry about. The difference, if any, would be tiny. Spend your optimization efforts where it matters.